# Linux shell - Creating Folder and Numbered text files in each folder

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, mkdir

i have been trying to create 100 folders with the names Client numbered 1-100 e.g. (client1, client2..client100) i also want to create a text file within each folder called client follwed by the same number on the folder. I have got to this peice of coding:

mkdir -p Client{1..100} && touch Client{1..100}/Client.txt

But this command line only generates a text file called client but is not numbered. Please can you help me figure out the coding to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You need a `for` loop.

Comment: Instead of {1..100} use {001..100} so all names will be the same length and will sort in order without any fuss. Or use {00..99} if numbers from 0 to 99 will work. BTW, what shell are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more concise:

```
for x in Client{1..100}; do
    mkdir -p $x
    touch $x/$x.txt
done
```

Comment: Thank you this piece of coding worked. I was able to complete the task and then much more stemmed from this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for x in {1..100}
do
    mkdir -p Client$x
    touch Client$x/Client$x.txt
done
```

Instead of `{1..100}` you can use the `seq` command and get additional features. For example:

```
for x in `seq -w 1 100`
do
   ....
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this coding out and will get back to you if i have any questions.

Comment: Don't use `seq`. `{1..N}` is better and more portable.

Comment: @janos: But `seq` has so many features (not needed by the OP)!

Comment: @rodrigo a guru on unix.stackexchange.com explicitly discouraged me. I don't remember his exact points but I was convinced. I know for a fact that BSD and UNIX don't have `seq` by default, and I really prefer using stuff that I can count on everywhere, always. Another thing, don't use backticks, `$()` is much better.